# Are the statements about the free $R$-module correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit.

If $F$ is a free $R$-module with finite rank, does it hold that each set of its generators contains a basis and that each linearly independent set of elements can be expanded into a basis?

$$$$

I think that both of them are true... But I am not eally sure... If they are correct, how exactly could we prove that?

Answer (score 6):

For a very simple counterexample to both statements, take $R=F=\mathbb{Z}$.  Then $\{2,3\}$ is a generating set which contains no basis, and $\{2\}$ is a linearly independent set which cannot be extended to a basis.

Comment: Why is $\{2,3\}$ a generating set?

Comment: We have that the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $F=\mathbb{Z}$ is free with basis $\{1\}$, or not?

Comment: What is in general a generating set?

Answer (score 2):

As a counterexample for the second consider $\mathbb{Z}^2$. This is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank $2$, but the set $\{(0,1),(2,0)\}$ does not extend to a basis

Comment: Why can this set not be extended to a basis?